# What does it actually mean for classes to be balanced?

Tags: data-mining, predictive-models, binary-data, unbalanced-classes, overfitting

I saw the following statement when reading Kuhn's APM: "The classes are fairly balanced; there are 111 samples in the first class and 97 in the second..." I thought balance would require the predictors to have the same frequency for each class (so there would be 111 samples in each class or 97 in each class). Is this not strictly true? If so, what test can I use to tell if the data is balanced?

Comment: I don't think there's any formal content to Kuhn's sentence - he's just saying that the classes have about the same number of samples and so are fairly balanced. Very unbalanced classes would have 1 samples in the first class and 100 samples in the second class (which does in fact occur in many real-world detection problems).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the purpose of prediction,
$$
\frac{111}{208} \approx 0.5 \approx \frac{97}{208}
$$
so it is considered to balanced *enough* to work. "fairly" != "perfectly".

A ratio of 150 to 58 would be considered not balanced by most people, I guess. I wouldn't bother to squeeze this into a mathematical formula; but if you want: within $\pm10\%$ of the expected value?

Or think of it in standard deviations. Assuming a 2 class problem, balanced, then $p=0.5$.
With $n=208$ observations, the expected value is $np=104$, and the variance is $np(1-p)=52$.
Thus, the standard deviation is $\sigma\approx 7.2$, and the $1\sigma$ confidence interval is $96...111$. From this point of view, you can easily reject the hypothesis that the deviation 111 vs. 97 is systematic: it may be just a random deviation from balancedness.

(If you want to formalize this into a *proper* hypothesis test, go ahead!)

Comment: +1, it might also help the OP if you addressed the question regarding whether the "predictors [need] to have the same frequency for each class".

Comment: Thanks for the actionable advice! For the purpose of reporting results, is this an acceptable justification? That they are close to balanced because they are within 1 SD of each other?

Comment: It's stronger than that: the observed values are within the 1 sigma confidence interval for events with ideal p=0.5 class probability. In 1/3 of experiments stronger deviations are to be expected.